# Optimize reshaping dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, io, python-3.11

I have a csv data log in the following format that i'm reading into dataframe then taking multiple steps to reshape it making it look like the below desired output. i got this to work, however it is taking 15 mins complete csv file with 100K rows. i feel like there gotta be a more efficient way. thank you in advance for your help.

my current approach is:

- split **Data** column into multiple
- create list of dataframes based on unique values of **Signals**
- loop through df list and update newly created columns names using **Signals 1st row value** + **new column(s) 1st row value**
- merge all df list using `reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, how='outer', on=['Timestamp']), df_list)`

**Input File Format:**

```
Index,Type,Signals,Timestamp,Data
614,type1,SignalName1,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757778999 EDT,"signalName=SignalName1, value1=0.00402894988656044, value2=true, value3=0, value4=false"
615,type2,SignalName2,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779000 EDT,"signalName=SignalName2, value1=0.004700441379100084, value2=true, value3=0, value4=true"
616,type3,SignalName3,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779001 EDT,"signalName=SignalName3, value1=32.0, value2=false, value3=4, value4=false"
617,type1,SignalName1,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779002 EDT,"signalName=SignalName1, value1=0.0053719328716397285, value2=true, value3=0, value4=false"
618,type2,SignalName2,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779003 EDT,"signalName=SignalName2, value1=0.005216674879193306, value2=false, value3=4, value4=false"
619,type3,SignalName3,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779004 EDT,"signalName=SignalName3, value1=0.0053719328716397285, value2=true, value3=0, value4=true"
620,type1,SignalName1,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779005 EDT,"signalName=SignalName1, value1=9.9627685546875, value2=false, value3=4, value4=false"
621,type2,SignalName2,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779006 EDT,"signalName=SignalName2, value1=0.00402894988656044, value2=true, value3=0, value4=false"
622,type3,SignalName3,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779007 EDT,"signalName=SignalName3, value1=93.6219711303711, value2=true, value3=0, value4=false"
623,type1,SignalName1,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779008 EDT,"signalName=SignalName1, value1=0.0585092157125473, value2=true, value3=0, value4=false"
624,type2,SignalName2,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779009 EDT,"signalName=SignalName2, value1=3.365873098373413, value2=true, value3=0, value4=true"
625,type3,SignalName3,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779010 EDT,"signalName=SignalName3, value1=9.9627685546875, value2=true, value3=0, value4=false"
626,type1,SignalName1,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779011 EDT,"signalName=SignalName1, value1=0.00402894988656044, value2=true, value3=0, value4=false"
627,type2,SignalName2,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779012 EDT,"signalName=SignalName2, value1=0.0053719328716397285, value2=false, value3=3, value4=false"
628,type3,SignalName3,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779013 EDT,"signalName=SignalName3, value1=0.00402894988656044, value2=true, value3=0, value4=false"
629,type1,SignalName1,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779014 EDT,"signalName=SignalName1, value1=0.2685966491699219, value2=true, value3=0, value4=false"
630,type2,SignalName2,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779015 EDT,"signalName=SignalName2, value1=0.006714915856719017, value2=true, value3=0, value4=true"
631,type3,SignalName3,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779016 EDT,"signalName=SignalName3, value1=0.0033574579283595085, value2=true, value3=0, value4=false"
632,type1,SignalName1,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779017 EDT,"signalName=SignalName1, value1=0.006714915856719017, value2=false, value3=5, value4=false"
633,type2,SignalName2,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779018 EDT,"signalName=SignalName2, value1=0.0033574579283595085, value2=true, value3=0, value4=false"
634,type3,SignalName3,2023-10-13 03:41:31.757779019 EDT,"signalName=SignalName3, value1=0.0033574579283595085, value2=true, value3=0, value4=false"
```

---

**Desired Output:**

note for the "nan", i'm using `df.fillna(method='ffill') & df.fillna(method='backfill')` to populate which is also taking too much time to complete.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have unpacked your 'Data' column into multiple columns, so you
have a dataframe df with columns (e.g.)...

```
Index   Type    Signals     Timestamp   Value1  Value2
```

... then you can get the reshaping you're looking for with

```py
dfp = df.pivot_table(index="Timestamp", columns="Signals", 
                     values=["Value1", "Value2"], aggfunc='first').reset_index()
dfp.columns = [f"{x[0]}_{x[1]}" for x in dfp.columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html)/[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) :

```
ext = df["Data"].str.extractall("(\w+)=(.+?)(?=,|$)").reset_index()

grp = (ext["match"].eq(0) & ext[1].eq(ext.at[0, 1])).cumsum()

signals = (
    ext.assign(
        sn=ext[1].where((m:=ext["match"].eq(0))).ffill(),
        col=lambda x: x["sn"].str.cat(x[0], sep="_"),
        idx1=grp.groupby(grp).cumcount()).loc[~m]
        .sort_values(["sn", "level_0"])
        .set_index(["level_0", "idx1", "col"])
        .drop(columns=["sn", "match", 0])
        .assign(idx2=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0, sort=False).ngroup())
        .droplevel(0).set_index("idx2", append=True).squeeze()
        .unstack(["col", "idx1"], sort=False).droplevel(1, axis=1)
)


out = df[["Timestamp"]].join(signals).set_index("Timestamp")
```

If the formatting is important, add a [`Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) :

```
(
    out.style.set_table_styles(
         [
              dict(
                  selector="th.col_heading",
                  props=[
                      ("writing-mode", "vertical-rl"),
                      ("transform", "rotateZ(180deg)"), 
                  ]
              )
         ]
    ).map(lambda v: "opacity: 0.5" if pd.isna(v) else "")
)
```

Output :

[image]